MATLAB unittest: set variable and use it across all test method in one test class
Is it possible in matlab.unittest.TestCase TestClass to declare property for test methods in such a way, so if it got changed in one test method, following methods use this updated value?
In example, if there is such example class:
classdef MyTestCase < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    properties
        id
    end

Then, i need to set this id property in such a way for all test methods, so i can retain it state across all the test methods, to make every next methods depending on the previous, e.g.
% set id = 10 before
methods(Test)
    function testMultiplicationByTwo(testCase)
        testCase.id = testCase.id * 2;
        testCase.verifyEqual(testCase.id, 20);
    end
    
    function testIdRemainsUnchanged(testCase)
        testCase.id = testCase.id + 10; % this testCase.id value should remain 20 after previous case
        testCase.verifyEqual(testCase.id, 30);
    end
end

Tried to do this in methods(TestClasSetup), but looks like it allows only testCase function parameter, so if i set id equals 10 there, it will resets for every new testCase. Any ways to share this updated value across all the test methods?
EDIT_1: other possible workaround may be to somehow store the ID after any actions done with it to some external/class-scope variable or parameter and then use it in following tests, e.g.
% set id = 10 before
methods(Test)
    function testMultiplicationByTwo(testCase)
        testCase.id = testCase.id * 2;
        updated_id = testCase.id
        % store updated_id somehow for its future use in following tests
        testCase.verifyEqual(testCase.id, 20);
    end
    
    function testIdRemainsUnchanged(testCase) % provide it here as param (testCase, updated_id)
        % or load somewhere from external source before test actions, then
        testCase.id = updated_id + 10; % should be 20 after previous case
        testCase.verifyEqual(testCase.id, 30);
    end
end

Regards,
N.

Test cases are supposed to be independent. They have to do exactly the same thing every time, even if you run one individually, or if you add or remove other test cases. So whatever you are planning to do with this persistent value is contrary to the concept of unit tests. Maybe if you explain your ultimate goal, we can point you in the right direction.

Well, there is some API test E2E scenarios e.g. 1/ create test workspace - 2/ create test board in this workspace use workspace ID as parameter - 3/ delete test board by created ID in this workspace - 4/ delete test workspace by ID. The goal is to have one scenario as TestClass with every step as a method, so once i get test ID in step 1/ only after test workspace is created, i need to store it for test 2/ and so on. I know that is is somehow against the concept of unit testing, but ti'd like to make it by analog of other test framework where it worked

Just out of curiosity, which test framework allows for this? I don’t know many, but the few I do know do not allow for inter-dependent test cases. I guess you could fudge something with global variables, but how are you going to force the four tests being run in the right order? I honestly think that your four steps are part of a single test.

From the docs: “Unit tests in a matlab.unittest.TestCase subclass must run independently, without unintentionally affecting one another. In addition, they must be repeatable, which means that a running test must not affect subsequent reruns of the same test.”

I used something similar with python pyATS framework, when complex E2E scenario was incorporated in one class with test methods as steps of its scenario with own checks. Although it isn't a unit test framework, so allow much more flexibility in different test structure approach.

It could be, but i'd like to rather keep 1 check (obj creation, obj creation inside it, obj deletion from it, obj deletion) per the lowest test level.  I assume, function with testCase parameter is the lowest here, and there are no subtests or substeps or something like this?
Except global variables, the idea is to read id as input parameter and then add some teardown-like method, that will update input parameters with any test data that is created by passed test, so then next one can use setup with updated data to use them

I still don’t understand what the advantage of 4 separate tests would be if you can’t run them separately.

It's not even the advantage reasons behind it, i can’t run them separately because they are dependent: 2/ uses in its request the ID value which is produced by test 1/ successful run. This value is generated in response, so i can't set it for test 2/ by myself.
So, either i need to share this produced value across the tests, or store somewhere in such a way to be able to get it from there for the next tests.
